# After loader fades out page always scrolls back to top (and I don't want to)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm afraid that my question is kinda stupid, but I have this problem for years and I've decided I'll ask. I'm using a div that covers the whole page. It is the first element after opening the body tag. I usually put some spinning element inside of it and type "loading...". I'm using simple script to fade out this div after the page is loaded.
Here's the simplified code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
<!-- All the content of the page goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
   position:fixed;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background: white
   z-index:99999;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

It works fine. But my problem occurs when you go to a page with an anchor (like "www.mysite.com/index.html#someanchor"). I see the scrollbar is in the correct position, the ".loader" div is on top of everything while page is fully loaded, and then suddenly after ".loader" fades away the page scrolls immediately back to the top. The same happens if you are in the middle of the page and hit F5 (or refresh button) - page reloads (I can see the scrollbars remain in the position I've been until that moment) and after loader fades it suddenly goes back to top. Is there a way I can avoid this? I've searched a lot of similar questions, I've tried setting time out, tried adding class, and still haven't find a way to fix this.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this. Are you running other scripts on the page?

Comment: @charles actually a lot :( Here's a livesite example: https://www.dedopene.com/

Comment: That's pretty intense. It looks like you are lazy loading a lot of content. If that's the case the anchor may not be far enough down the page to make a difference to the scroll position until all the images are in place. If that's the case, the page won't be scrolled to the anchor or the user's previous scroll distance when the loader disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is very embarrassing, but thanks to Charles Bamford (who asked: "Are you running other scripts on the page?") I've figured out that Modernizr was causing this problem. I'm not sure this question will be of any use to anybody, so I'm thinking about deleting it...